# Call to UIWebView crashing my app in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I have a WebView in my storyboard.  I created an outlet property to that webview in my view controller file.  Then in my code in I'm calling it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"news1" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"/HTML"]];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}
```

The problem is my app is crashing when I run this and I don't really know why.  I get this error, but I need help deciphering what the issue is.

```
2014-05-20 20:18:10.214 MyApp[1789:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01f7b1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019fe8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01f7afbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Foundation                          0x0161a92b -[NSURL(NSURL) initFileURLWithPath:] + 123
    4   Foundation                          0x0161a7fd +[NSURL(NSURL) fileURLWithPath:] + 67
    5   MyApp                               0x00011c3d -[LVGTutorialVC viewDidLoad] + 205
    6   UIKit                               0x007dd33d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    7   UIKit                               0x00803345 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 39
    8   UIKit                               0x0080385b -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 235
    9   UIKit                               0x00803953 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 78
    10  UIKit                               0x008048cc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 645
    11  UIKit                               0x008054e9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    12  UIKit                               0x009460d1 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    13  UIKit                               0x0072d964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01a1082b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01de245a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    16  QuartzCore                          0x01dd6244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    17  QuartzCore                          0x01dd60b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    18  QuartzCore                          0x01d3c7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    19  QuartzCore                          0x01d3db85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    20  QuartzCore                          0x01d3e258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01f4336e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01f432bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01f21254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01f209d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x01f207eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x03eab5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x03eab42b GSEventRun + 104
    28  UIKit                               0x006bef9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    29  MyApp                               0x0002158d main + 141
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x0262c701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML file isn't in your bundle or isn't at the path specified. Check the case of the file and folder name. If you build/run in the simulator, you can look through the bundle inside of ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications.

Comment: My HTML file is in the bundle.  I created a folder group named HTML in xcode and added the file there. How do I look through the bundle in the simulator?

Comment: OK now I see what you are saying.  I navigated to that bundle path on my machine, I do not see the file in there.  But how do I place it in there?  Do I do it manually and just drop it in or what?  I put the file in the xcode project and I thought it will get added upon Build/Run, so I'm not sure what next to do.

Comment: Add the HTML folder to the Xcode project by dragging it from The Finder into Xcode. When asked, select "Create Folder References". This will make sure that the HTML folder itself will get copied into your bundle rather than just the files within it.

Comment: Thank you Eric, this finally worked when I did a Drag and "Create Folder References" instead.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `loadRequest` if you want to load html locally. use this

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I am still getting the same crash error.  To EricS's point, maybe it's not finding the file.  But that doesn't make sense I put it in there, I can see it in xcode physically unless I am missing something.